# What's the gain I can have with blocks over regular methods?

Tags: ruby

I am a Java programmer, and I am learning Ruby...

But I don't get where those blocks of codes can give me gain... like what's the purpose of passing a block as an argument ? why not have 2 specialized methods instead that can be reused ?

Why have some code in a block that cannot be reused ?

I would love some code examples...

Thanks for the help !

Comment: In addition to the answer below, note that blocks in Ruby are _closures_, providing easy access to local variable defined in the same scope without needing to explicitly pass them to some method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider some of the things you would use anonymous classes for in Java. e.g. often they are used for pluggable behaviour such as event listeners or to parametrize a method that has a general layout.

Imagine we want to write a method that takes a list and returns a new list containing the items from the given list for which a specified condition is true. In Java we would write an interface:

```
interface Condition {
    boolean f(Object o);
}
```

and then we could write:

```
public List select(List list, Condition c) {
    List result = new ArrayList();
    for (Object item : list) {
        if (c.f(item)) {
            result.add(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then if we wanted to select the even numbers from a list we could write:

```
List even = select(mylist, new Condition() {
    public boolean f(Object o) {
        return ((Integer) o) % 2 == 0;
    }
});
```

To write the equivalent in Ruby it could be:

```
def select(list)
  new_list = []
  # note: I'm avoid using 'each' so as to not illustrate blocks
  # using a method that needs a block
  for item in list
    # yield calls the block with the given parameters
    new_list << item if yield(item)
  end
  return new_list
end
```

and then we could select the even numbers with simply

```
even = select(list) { |i| i % 2 == 0 }
```

Of course, this functionality is already built into Ruby so in practice you would just do

```
even = list.select { |i| i % 2 == 0 }
```

As another example, consider code to open a file. You could do:

```
f = open(somefile)
# work with the file
f.close
```

but you then need to think about putting your `close` in an `ensure` block in case an exception occurs whilst working with the file. Instead, you can do

```
open(somefile) do |f|
  # work with the file here
  # ruby will close it for us when the block terminates
end
```

Comment: Hum... thanks, that was a very nice example... I think I will need some time to get used to think like that. But that why I am trying to learn ruby :D it's a nice solution when you get it.

Comment: Take a look at the [Enumerable mixin](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) - lots of good examples of methods that make use of blocks in there. I think getting used to blocks is a 2 part process of 1) start to understand some of the standard methods that use blocks 2) start to think how methods you write yourself can take advantage of accepting blocks. I've also added one more example to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind blocks is that it is a highly localized code where it is useful to have the definition at the call site. You can use an existing function as a block argument. Just pass it as an additional argument, and prefix it with an &