# Weird (for me) using of methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I`m new to rails, so that question may be stupid.
I have seen a lot of code like this

```
method do |x|
 x.something
 x.blabla
end
```

For example some snippet from migrate

```
create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
```

What happens here ? |t| is passed to create_table method or ?
I can`t fugure out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blocks & Procs in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560571/blocks-procs-in-ruby)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783166/whats-the-gain-i-can-have-with-blocks-over-regular-methods

Comment: Also: don't answer duplicates, If really you have nothing to add to existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|x|` is a parameter being passed to the block.  It is a feature of Ruby, not specific to Ruby on Rails.

Here's a very contrived example of how you might implement a function which accepts a block:

```
# invoke proc on each element of the items array
def each(items, &proc)
  for i in (0...items.length)
    proc.call(items[i])
  end
end

my_array = [1,2,3];

# call 'each', passing in items and a block which prints the element
each my_array do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Effectively, you're invoking `each` and passing it two things: An array (`my_array`) and a block of code to execute. Internally `each` loops over each item in the array and invokes the block on that item. The block receives a single parameter, `|i|`, which is populated by `each` when it calls proc: `proc.call(items[i])`.